# Why "return false;" is not equal to "boolean score= false; return score;" ? AP-1 > scoresIncreasing

Tags: java, return, boolean

I want to ask about the following code ,specifically for the line 7.
This is an exercise with CodingBat AP-1 > scoresIncreasing, and it reads like this

"Given an array of scores, return true if each score is equal or greater than the one before. The array will be length 2 or more."

The following solution is correct but if I change the line:7 from "return false;" to "score=false;"  the method returns another incorrect result.

**Please tell me what is the difference between "return false;" and "score=false;" and why is this happening?**

```
 public boolean scoresIncreasing(int[] scores) {
  boolean score = false;
  for(int i = 0; i < scores.length-1; i++){
    if(scores[i+1] >= scores[i]){
      score = true;
    }else {
      return false; 
    }
  }
  return score;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Walk through the code mentally on paper, and you'll see why this code is behaving as its behaving. Also, you could step through the code using a debugger, checking the state of fields as the code runs, and this too will show you why this is happening.

Comment: The difference is that you're immediately returning from the method in one instance, and setting a variable inside a loop in the other

Comment: If you make it `score = false;`, there's a chance that the loop does not end there, and it may take `true` in a subsequent iteration.

Comment: If you remove the early return the value returned **only** depends on the last two scores compared, all prior to that are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because with "return false;" in the 7th line you are exiting method early, with correct result, as algorithm implies.

If you are just assigning false value to score, you continue looping, so, result becoome invalid in some cases (just because further you may re-assign score with true).

Answer (score 0):

- Well because `return false` stops the execution of the for loop and returns the value to where the `scoresIncreasing` function was called from as soon as it counters a value of score which is less than value of previous score.
- Whereas when you use `score=false` the for loops runs through complete array and then returns `true` or `false` only on the condition of whether the last elements of array is greater or smaller than it's previous value